# Problem with clientBundle/Eclipse/Maven @source-tag

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, clientbundle

i tried to use ClientBundle and @source Annotation but without changing eclipse-project-settings, Eclipse can't find any resources because of exlude-filter set for "src/main/resources". The [gwt-issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4600) describes the problem in detail and lists some (bad) workarounds.

Is there any way to configure resources folder/filtering in pom (probably in gwt-maven-plugin part) to get this configuration item out of .project-file?

Or is there a "real" solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working in what I think is The Maven Way (using Maven3 at any rate) by adding build resources. For example (for use in a GWT jar module)

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.java</include>
                <include>**/*.gwt.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/images</directory>
            <targetPath>images</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources/styles</directory>
            <targetPath>styles</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.css</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```